# DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged not firing (yes, AutoPostBack="true")

Tags: asp.net

I hate to put another one of these up here, but the 20 other questions of this type have been answered with "set `AutoPostBack="true"`", which I've already done. I believe my problem is more in the way I'm setting the items in the DropDownList, but I'm new at ASP.NET, so I'm not sure what the proper solution is.

Here's my control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DrpProduct" CssClass="input-xxlarge"  runat="server"    AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"     OnSelectedIndexChanged="DrpProduct_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

And here's where I'm setting it in the code-behind of the page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  Repository = new ProductRepository();
  Products = Repository.List();

  if (Products.Any())
    foreach (Product product in Products) {
      DrpProduct.Items.Add(new ListItem(product.Name, product.Name));
    }
}
```

And finally my listener:

```
protected void DrpProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eArgs) 
{
  //code omitted. I have a breakpoint here that never gets hit anyways.
}
```

They render and display properly, but the OnSelectedIndexChanged event is not being hit when I use the dropdown. I've read that adding items to the dropdown this way can be problematic if not done at the proper stage of the page's lifecycle, but I've tried it on multiple other stages to no effect. I'm doing it this way (rather than data bound objects, etc) for a specific reason, so would like to make this code work for me.

**EDIT:** By request, here is my ProductRepository code:

```
public class ProductRepository
{
  private IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

public ProductRepository()
{
      Products = new List<Product> {
        new Product("Grand Theft Auto V", "A video game that lets you kill hookers.", 59.99m), 
        new Product("Fallout 4", "lol u wish", 99.99m), 
        new Product("XCOM: Enemy Unknown", "Probably one of the better games you'll ever play.", 39.99m),
         new Product("The Bureau: XCOM Declassified", "The game NO ONE asked for. Or wanted.", 59.99m),
        new Product("Rome 2: Total War", "There'd better be phalanxes.", 59.99m)
      }; 
}

  public IList<Product> List() 
  {
    return Products;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe not relevant to solve your issue, but it's a good idea to check for the Page Postback before binding your DropDownList.

Comment: It might be due to where you are adding elements to the control. try in Page_Load or Page_PreRender. Also rather than adding them one by one you could set a DataSource.

Comment: Is there any form validation going on in this page?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @andrewb - I've tried my code in the first 8 stages (PreInit - PreRender) with no difference. That was my original thought too, but I'm starting to think it's something more subtle than just where I put the code.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - Could you elaborate on your Page Postback comment. I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Also, no at this time there shouldn't be any validation going on but I'm going to double check...

Comment: All this mess is one of the reasons I'm loving MVC instead of WebForms. LOL

Comment: @LoganDangerBlack Could you make sure you have `AutoEventWireup="true"` in Page like this `<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" ...%>`

Comment: @Win - Yup, AutoEventWireup="true"

Comment: @MelanciaUK -  Np. I'm using MVC a bit at work and don't know that I would ever willingly use ASP.NET on a greenfield project again. :p However, before you deleted your answer you mentioned an UpdatePanel, which I am currently not using. I'm not sure that it's relevant. I'll actually probably add one later on, after I can get these damn events to hit!!

Comment: @LoganDangerBlack Could you create a new aspx page without master page? Do not add any control except - **DrpProduct** to ***aspx*** and **Page_Init**, and **DrpProduct_SelectedIndexChanged** events ***aspx.cs***. Then debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, figured it out. It was actually a pretty stupid mistake on my part.

My DropDownList was just hanging out on the page, rather than being contained within a `<form>`.  Wasn't aware that would negate the SelectedIndexChanged event. So, changed my code in my .aspx file to:

```
<form ID="ProductForm" runat="server">
  <asp:DropDownList .... />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is tested and works. I'd be interested to know how you're defining `Products`? For brevity, I've left out the `aspx` code.

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    List<Product> products = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            products = new List<Product> 
            { 
                new Product{ Name = "ProductOne" },
                new Product{ Name = "ProductTwo" }
            };

            if (products.Count > 0)
                foreach (var product in products)
                    DrpProduct.Items.Add(new ListItem(product.Name, product.Name));
        }
    }

    protected void DrpProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // break point in here is getting hit
    }

}

class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Try replacing the data you're getting from your repository with a hard coded list of type `Product`like I have and see how you get on. This will prove that your setup is indeed correct, and the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: My ProductRepository.List() is doing the same thing you're doing. It's just a mock-up for testing.
I'd be more interested in seeing your .aspx code because, despite a bit of abstraction difference, our code-behinds are doing the same thing...

Comment: My `aspx` code is the exact same as yours. Please show how you're defining `Products`.

Comment: Done! Check original post.

Comment: The variables in the constructor are 'Name', 'Description', and 'Price' in that order.

Comment: Where and how are you actually declaring `Producucts` and `Repository` in your code behind? Try what I showed. If you're so convinced they're the same, then it will work.

Comment: Actually, it was something even simpler and stupider on my behalf. I didn't have my DropDownList wrapped in a `form` element. I wasn't aware that that was required for the control events to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've wired up the EventHandler correctly.

Try switching to Designer mode in Visual Studio and double-clicking on the DropDownList to make sure that the CodeBehind opens up to the actual DrpProduct_SelectedIndexChanged method.

This is always a good way to test your code and make sure that everything is wired up.

You can also try wiring up your EventHandler programmatically like this...

```
DrpProduct.Click += new eventHandler(DrpProduct_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's possible you forgot to set the AutoPostBack of the control to true...I will not admit if that was the solution for me 8)